# Do I need a "ones" at the end of this sentence?

Tags: word-usage

> Things that haven't occurred yet are the most scary (ones).

To I need that *ones* at the end? Why or why not?

Comment: No, but you do probably need an article...*The* things that haven't occurred yet... We would need more context to decide.

Comment: @alexchenco You probably want *the scariest*, even though *most scary* seems to also be in use. Click [here](http://goo.gl/s8rtW6) for Google Ngram results of `most scary,scariest`.

Comment: @Damkerng T. Oh you're right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Superlative adjectives can stand on their own as quasi-nouns after the copula.  There is no need to carry over "ones" if you're feeling grammatical vertigo, as if the adjective is looking over the edge of a cliff.

**Apples picked in the morning are the coolest.**

Comment: Plus one. This also shows that the definite article is not *necessary* in the first noun phrase. But then again, (as you commented) in a certain context, it might be. I.e., referring to a *definite* set of apples rather than making a general observation.

Answer (score 1):

It's *ellipsis*. [This means](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ellipsis) *the omission of one or more words that are obviously understood but that must be supplied to make a construction grammatically complete.*

Somehow, I feel that you *do* require 'ones' to make the sentence *appear* complete. I spoke that sentence twice *without* 'ones', but it did not give the fullness to the sentence!

Answer (score 1):

I think, it makes no difference in meaning if you use ones at the end of the sentence. Both the sentences with/without "ones" as mentioned below are grammatically correct. In fact, we can use ones as a pronoun to refer to the kind of things/persons just mentioned to avoid repetition.

The things that haven't occurred yet are the most scary.

The things that haven't occured yet are the most scary things/ones.